# trying to reference an element in a multidimensional object array that is inside an object array

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object array (shown below). Each object array holds a multidimensional object array. This all seems fine until I actually try referencing an element.

```
 object[] dataArrays = new object[3];
 object[,] valueArray = (object[,])Rng.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
 dataArrays[0] = valueArray;
```

So I thought I could simply do something like the line below,

> dataArrays[0][3,4]

However I get an error message saying the *Cannot apply indexing with [ ] to an experssion of type object*, so how do I reference an element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to cast the element, with the declaration as it stands. The problem is that the type of `dataArrays[0]` is just `object`, not `object[,]`. It could be a string, or any other reference.

If `dataArrays` *always* holds `object[,]` references, I'd suggest you make that clear in the declaration:

```
object[][,] dataArrays = new object[3][,];
```

The rest of your existing code will work, but so will `dataArrays[0][3,4]`.

(I'd also suggest converting the data to a more usefully-typed representation as early as possible, if you can. I understand that that may not be possible, depending on your context.)